# Trying to pass an object as a parameter is breaking the variable. Should I be refactoring this?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass a date object as a parameter? I was attempting to set up another set interval to refresh the greeting for automatic updates when I noticed I was using a new Date() a lot. I tried to refactor the code a bit but ended up breaking things. My new code does not recognize the 'today' variable even for the first selector where it was working prior.

```
//Variables
const today = new Date();
const weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

//Selectors
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = weekday[today.getDay()];
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString();

//Functions

//Greeting based on local time
function timeOfDay(today) {
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML =
    today.getHours() < 12
      ? "Good Morning"
      : today.getHours() >= 18
      ? "Good Evening"
      : "Good Afternoon";
}
  setInterval(timeOfDay, 1000 * 60 * 60);

//Get and display local time
function getTime(today) {
  const currentTime = today.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = currentTime;
}
setInterval(getTime, 1);
```

The code below was working fine I was just trying to see if there was another way to do it without constantly creating a new date object.

```
//Greeting based on local time
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML =
  new Date().getHours() < 12
    ? "Good Morning"
    : new Date().getHours() >= 18
    ? "Good Evening"
    : "Good Afternoon";

//Get and display local time
const today = new Date();
const weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = weekday[today.getDay()];
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString();
function getTime() {
  const time = new Date();
  const currentTime = time.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = currentTime;
}
setInterval(getTime, 1);
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: You aren't passing a parameter to `getTime` so `today` is undefined inside the function (the parameter declaration shadows the outer variable declaration). You would need to pass the outer variable `today` [as an argument in your `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#parameters) call `setInterval(getTime, 1, today);` but keep in mind that your original version was calculating `today` on every call where as your refactored version will calculate it once when loaded and then use that date for all future calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that when you create a new `Date` object, its value is the time it was created. It doesn't change after that.

Thankfully there is an easy solution.

You don't need to create a new `Date` object everytime, just use the object itself as a function.

```js
var now = new Date();
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(`new Date(): ${now}`);
  console.log(`Date(): ${Date()}`);
  console.log("");
}, 1000)
```